# How to reference a .NET standard library from a Xamarin iOS binding project?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, .net-standard

I've created a Xamarin iOS binding project for an iOS framework. I want some of the generated binding classes to implement interfaces from a .NET Standard class library. This fails because I cannot reference .NET standard assemblies from within that library. How can I make this compile, or is there another (better) approach?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download and unzip the demo project from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/ios-samples/bindingsample/
2. Add a .NET standard class library project "Api".
3. Add a file IApi.cs to the Api project:

```
    namespace Api
    {
        public interface IApi
        {
            Result Status { get; }
        }
    }

    public enum Result
    {
        Success,
        Error
    }
```

4. Make the binding project reference the Api project.
5. Go to Extras.cs and add this code to the XMUtilities class:

```
    partial class XMUtilities : IApi
    {
        public Result Status => string.IsNullOrEmpty(Speak()) ? Result.Error : Result.Success;
```

6. Build the project. It fails with 2 errors saying

> "Error CS0012: The type 'Enum' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard,
>   Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
>   (CS0012) (XMBindingLibrary)"

I cannot find a way to add that reference. In particular, the hint in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42497735/1004651 did not work for me, and I am not sure whether it is the same problem.

Background:
I have a 3rd party lib with versions for Android and iOS. I want to hide both of these behind a common API and create multiple Xamarin Forms project that build upon that API. The approach outlined above worked well with an Android binding project, but now I am struggling with the iOS counterpart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't work that way.

You cannot 'add' features to your native library in the binding project nor can you reference other library: You have to consider it just as a wrapper.

That being said, you can create another Xamarin native project (or a net standard) that will have a ref to your binding project and to the net standard lib containing your interface. In this project, you will be able able to subclass and add the required behaviour.